# Adding pull request build status to Github

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pull request trigger for Github in VSTS. I also want to add this trigger to the required checks in Github and show build status on pull request page like below.

[image]

I also checked branch protection page on Github but there are no status checks available.

[image]

Is it possible to do this in VSTS or do I need to create a PR status server mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/how-to/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions) ?

Comment: Have you had any luck setting up web hooks or services?

Comment: There is a VSTS webhook in Github repository and VSTS initiates builds for PRs using this webhook right now. I also added status events to the webhook but nothing changed.

Comment: did you check logs on VSTS? maybe it's connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked **Advanced settings => Report build status** option and VSTS automatically sends commit status to Github.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Configuration for enabling the [GitHub commit status checks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-status-checks/) in Azure DevOps seems to have changed.

1. Ensure [Azure Pipelines](https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines/) is installed for your organization or repository
2. Edit your Azure DevOps Build (Pipeline)
3. Click on the **Get sources** step
4. Under the GitHub configuration, select **Report build status**
5. **Save** (**& queue**, if you wish) your updated configuration

If someone on the DevOps team sees this, reporting commit status should be enabled by default!

[image: Configure GitHub commit status in Azure DevOps]

Answer (score 2):

There isn’t such setting in VSTS, you can refer to this workflow to do it:

1. Get a commit sha
2. Create a status check context through [REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/)

Post: `https://api.github.com/repos/[owner]/[repository]/statuses/[commit sha]`

Body(application/json):

```
{
  "state": "success",
  "target_url": "XXX",
  "description": "Build verify",
  "context": "continuous-integration/vsts"
}
```

Then check the related status check in branch protect page:

[image]

Note: the target_url can be badge URL (Check Badge enabled in Options of build definition)

3. Create a build definition to create status through REST API (The same as step 2: change commit sha and body) in VSTS continuous integration (Enable **continuous integration**) for current commit
4. Create a build definition to update status of current commit through REST API in VSTS (Enable **pull request validation**)

Answer (score 0):

From Jenkins, Pull-Request Status can be created/updated from pipeline

```
script {
    pullRequest.createStatus(status: "success",
                             context: "validate-profiles",
                             description: "Profiles file validated successfully!",
                             targetUrl: "$RUN_DISPLAY_URL")
}
```

[image]

Tons of other things can be done from pipeline avoiding explicit calls to GitHub API

**Make a comment on Pull-Request**

```
pullRequest.comment("Your service-profile request is received. Please track ticket progress here: "+ticketData['_links']['web'])
```

**Create & Add Labels to Pull-Request**

```
pullRequest.addLabel(env.TICKET_ID)
```

**Update Title for the Pull-Request**

```
pullRequest.setTitle("["+env.TICKET_ID+"] Profile Review Request for "+env.CHANGE_TARGET)
```