# How to display the build status in pull requests in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I would like to display the status of pipeline builds in Azure Pipelines in corresponding pull requests in Azure DevOps Repos.

I'd like to have some indicator which shows that a build succeeded of failed, like this (Note that this is a screenshot from the microsoft docs page, also mentioned below):
[image: PR status]

In my research I came across different solutions, including the following ones:

- [Adding pull request build status to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324065/adding-pull-request-build-status-to-github).

  - In the screenshots, there's a "Report build status" checkbox which doesn't exist (anymore?). Be aware that there's a GitHub-repo selected, so maybe the checkbox has never existed at all for the Azure DevOps Repos option.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-status?view=azure-devops#pull-request-status.

  - It seems to be possible to do this with the help of the Status API, but I expect Azure DevOps to provide this feature natively for Azure DevOps Repos and Azure Pipelines, as things like this should be one of the main benefits of such an integrated system.
- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3104

  - I just came across this issue on GitHub. It seems to be a question/request for exactly this behaviour, but with no comments so far (as of today).

Comment: Hi Alex; can I check: do you already have the CI pipeline enabled in the _Build validation_ section of your branch's _Build Policies_ settings screen?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Thanks! With an activated Pre-Merge build, the status is indeed displayed. Do you know if it's also possible to just show the status of the latest build of the feature branch (the branch to be merged) instead of triggering an additional build?

Comment: Sorry Alex, I don't know if that's possible. It's worth checking in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds?view=azure-devops) though; it confirms there that builds triggered by the PR (by branch policies) are displayed on the PR screen, and it might describe further functionality too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The key is to configure the CI pipeline as a Build Validation requirement, in the Build Policies settings of your master branch.

When that's configured, the PR will automatically kick off a CI build, and display its status in the PR screen.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will this setting work also for ongoing PRs (created before changing the setting that you mentioned)?

Comment: @mnj yes it will also work for pr created before. I just tested it. It was not showing initially but when I tried to complete PR merged failed and then pipeline view shown on PR.